# Copy Production Cloud Datastore to Dev Server Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, database-backups

According to the online documentation, in order to backup data you must go to the Datastore Admin after you have enabled it. It is enabled on my production server.

The to import you simply go to the admin page again, and select the back name you just created. I have downloaded the backup from my Google Bucket onto a local drive, following all the steps of this handy guide found here http://gbayer.com/big-data/app-engine-datastore-how-to-efficiently-export-your-data/

Now that I have the data locally, I am stuck in trying to get it into a local dev server.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=dev~<APP_ID> --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=<lengthyfilename>.backup_info
04:03 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20161230.160323
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20161230.160323.sql3
[ERROR   ] [Thread-1] RestoreThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", line 1555, in run
    self.PerformWork()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", line 2838, in PerformWork
    cursor.execute('select id, value from result')
DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Inside the local admin page, there is not a restore option in any of the Cloud Datastore pages, I'm at a loss. All the answers I find are five years old, on outdated packages. How do you restore an Cloud Datastore Backup into a Developer App Server?

Comment: Are you using the `gcloud` tool as told in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#updating_and_deleting_indexes)?

Comment: No. My server is started using dev_appserver.py and I'm not aware that you can start an external datastore emulation when using the dev app server.

Comment: Perhaps this helps?  http://johanndutoit.net/importing-a-datastore-backup-for-local-development-on-app-engine/

Comment: @GAEfan I think i came across this before. If I use a folder name as it suggest, I get the error `OperationalError: unable to open database file` Clearly because it is not a file name. But if i give it anyone of the files in the backup I get this error `DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database`. The latter error arises on the `<filename>.backup_info files and the `output-0` buried in the folders.

Comment: @GAEfan I was able to download my most vital entities for testing using his method. (I tweeted to him and he updated the page!) Sadly though, the upload process that he provides only works with the download process also referenced by him. Not the copied backupfiles from the Datastore Admin.

Comment: After much pain trying to do this, I wrote my own script:  

https://github.com/GAEfan/app_engine_backup_loader  

Much faster and less error-prone (and less expensive!) than the bulkloader or appcfg.py download_data methods

Comment: The data you downloaded via "managed export" over console storage bucket is in the form of LevelDB. The problem is it not loadable into local development server. `appcfg.py` upload_data works with the data with download_data command. Unfortunately, there is no documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of using the Datastore emulator is that it [now supports import and export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import).

You can read about starting dev_appserver with the Datastore emulator [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/migrate-cloud-datastore-emulator).